# vbscript issue for removing trusted site

Tags: vbscript

I have a script to add the trusted sites to IE.

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

strComputer = "."
Set objReg=GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\" _
    & "ZoneMap\Domains\" & "https://www.google.com"

objReg.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath

strValueName = "*"

dwValue = 2

objReg.SetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, strValueName, dwValue
```

The trusted sites are added successfully. But there is a problem here....
I am not able to remove the trusted sites added through the script which is a serious problem

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
'**************************************************************************

'VBScript to remove all IE opened tab urls from the Trusted Site list

'***************************************************************************

Dim Windows

Dim tabUrl

On Error Resume Next

Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001

Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set Windows = CreateObject(Shell.Windows)

For Each Window In Shell.Windows

    If InStr(1, Window.FullName, "iexplore.exe", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

        tabUrl = Window.LocationUrl

        Msgbox tabUrl

        strComputer = "."

        Set objReg=GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

        strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\" & "ZoneMap\Domains\" &tabUrl

        objReg.DeleteKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath

        strValueName = "*"

        dwValue = 2

        objReg.SetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, strValueName, dwValue

    End If

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

[The Scripting Guys](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.08.scriptingguy.aspx) article tells you how to delete keys and tells you why delete sometimes doesn't work